# IF(:old.actDepartDateTime IS NULL) THEN

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

backs up the flight ID, ticket number and seat number for any deleted ticket if the ticket corresponds to a flight that has not yet departed.

CREATE SEQUENCE generateKey
    START WITH 100
    INCREMENT BY 1;

```
CREATE TABLE backUpTicket
(
cancelledKey NUMBER NOT NULL,
flightID char(9) NOT NULL,
ticketNum varchar2(5) NOT NULL,
seatNum NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(cancelledKey)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER backUpTicketCancelled
BEFORE DELETE ON FLIGHT
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO backUpTicket
    VALUES
    (generateKey.nextVal, :old.flightID, :old.TicketNum, :old.seatNum);

    IF(:old.actDepartDateTime IS NULL) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Flight has not departed yet');
    END IF;

END backUpTicket;
/
```

the error coming in the IF(:old.actDepartDateTime IS NULL) as bad bind operator

Comment: What are the columns in table backUpTicketCancelled?

Comment: it is just the question and the answer, the trigger is named as backupTicketCancelled

Comment: Sorry, I mean What are the columns in table TICKET - i.e. the one the trigger is on?

Comment: @TonyAndrews can you help me?
FLIGHT(flightID, estDepartureDateTime, actDepartDateTime, actArriveDateTime, avgSpeed,avgHeight, estDuration, estFuel, haulType, captainStaffID, firstOfficerStaffID, routeID, aircraftID)

TICKET(ticketNum, luggageLimit, seatNum, classCode,medicalCondition, mealChoice, customerID,flightID)

Comment: hope the above helps... @TonyAndrews

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @TonyAndrews can you help me one last time?

Comment: Also, your assignment says to back up the ticket *if the ticket corresponds to a flight that has not yet departed*, but your code backs up all tickets regardless of the flight status and then conditionally prints a debug message for developers.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson i will do BEFORE DELETE ON TICKET to BEFORE DELETE ON FLIGHT

Comment: @WilliamRobertson what will be next?

Comment: Your assignment says you should back  up deleted tickets, not deleted flights.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I have no idea how to this? can you give me a solution, at least say where my logic is wrong? Please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your trigger should be on the TICKET table, not the FLIGHT table. Second, you're not supposed to create the backup of the ticket if the flight has already departed. Your code always creates the backup. I suggest the following might work better:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER backUpTicketCancelled
  BEFORE DELETE ON TICKET
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  rowFlight  FLIGHT%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
    INTO rowFlight
    FROM FLIGHT f
    WHERE f.FLIGHTID = :OLD.FLIGHTID;

  IF rowFlight.actDepartDateTime IS NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO backUpTicket
        (CANCELLEDKEY,        FLIGHTID,      TICKETNUM,      SEATNUM)
      VALUES
        (generateKey.nextVal, :old.flightID, :old.TicketNum, :old.seatNum);
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || ': ' ||
        'Flight ' || :OLD.FLIGHTID || ' departed at ' ||
        TO_CHAR(rowFlight.actDepartDateTime, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ||
        ' so ticket #' || :OLD.TICKETNUM || ' for seat #' || :OLD.SEATNUM ||
        ' is not eligible for backup');
  END IF;    
END backUpTicket;
```

Also, the name of the backup table is supposed to be `BACKUP_TICKET` not `backUpTicket`, so you'll probably get marked down for that.

In addition, while I realize this is a homework assignment, this is a very poor design choice. You should create a procedure which performs all actions required to delete a ticket, rather than having "magic code" buried in a trigger which performs this kind of business decision.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, your trigger is on table `TICKET` but the column `actDepartDateTime` is in table `FLIGHT`.  You can only access columns from the trigger's table using `:OLD` and `:NEW`.  To get `actDepartDateTime` you will need to select from the `FLIGHT` table using the `:OLD.flightID` value.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER backUpTicketCancelled

BEFORE DELETE ON FLIGHT

FOR EACH ROW


Will it work now?

Comment: Well that bit will work, but then you won't be able to back up the ticket?

Comment: IF(compare flightID of flight and ticket) AND
(:old.actDepartDateTime IS NULL) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Flight has not departed yet');
    END IF;

Comment: i did not get that